# Esperar resposta do usuário no telegram - Python

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Como posso esperar a resposta do usuário após a execução de um comando? Estou usando Python 3.6 e a lib telegram-bot-python.

Exemplo:

```
usuario - /apel
bot - Qual o seu apelido?
usuario - dfop
bot - Uau, seu apelido é dfop
```

Fiz até aqui:

```
def apel(bot, update):
        update.message.reply_text('Qual o seu apelido?')
        resposta = ??
        bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id, text = "Uau, seu apelido é %s", resposta)

updater = Updater(token)
dispatcher = self.updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('/apel', apel))
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Comment: Se parece muito com sua última pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/335178/5878. Qual é a diferença?

Comment: Achei que a última ficou um pouco confusa então refiz a pergunta tentando simplificar o máximo possível pra facilitar quem for ler. Posso deletar o post anterior se for dar algum problema.

Comment: Você poderia ter editado a pergunta anterior no botão editar logo abaixo das `tag's` da pergunta. Mas agora que já fez essa e a outra não tem nenhuma interação, é melhor remover a antiga.

Answer (score -4):

Preciso saber algumas informações do seu projeto.

Tipo:

```
 - Qual a biblioteca que você está usando ?
 - Qual é a versão do python utilizada ?
```

Bora dizer que você está utilizando a biblioteca pyTelegramBotAPI:

- Utilize o método register_next_step_handler()

Exemplo utilizando esse método no seu codigo:

```
 def apel(bot, update):
    msg = update.message.reply_text('Qual o seu apelido?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, nome_de_uma_funcao)
    bot.send_message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id, text = "Uau, seu apelido é %s", resposta)


def nome_de_uma_funcao(message):
  # Guardando a resposta do usuario em uma variavel
  resposta = message.text
  print(resposta)
```

Espero ter ajudado!